# Can the cubic mean- geometric mean inequality by a sum of 8 weighted squares?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Does there exist 8 trivariate polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_8$ and a function $s:\{1, \ldots, 8\}\to \{1, x,y,z\}$ such that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz = s(1)f_1(x,y,z)^2 +\cdots + s(8)f_8(x,y,z)^2$ for all real $x,y,z$?

The identity $2(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz) = (x+ y + z)[(x-y)^2 + (y-z)^2 + (z-x)^2]$ witnesses that 9 trivariate polynomials is enough.

Comment: I don't get it. You can just set $f_1 = x^3 + y^3 + z^3 - 3xyz$, $s(1)=1$, and $0$ for all the other f's and s's. So 1 polynomial is enough. What is it that I'm missing, and why is it that your question title mentions weighted squares whereas the question itself does not?

Comment: I missed out the squares.